# Grails cannot display state name in search results page

Tags: grails

I've set up a search page in my Grails application using the searchable plug-in. My search is working fine but I'm running into a small problem. In my search results (which display a name and a state), the state is not showing up.

I have two domains:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    State state
}

class State {
    String name
    String code

    String toString()
        return this.name
    }
}
```

In my *search.gsp* view, I have the following:

```
<g:each var="result" in="${searchResult.results}">

            <div class="searchResult">
                <div class="searchPerson">
                    <g:link controller="person" action="show" id="${result.id}">
                        ${result.lastName}, ${result.firstName}
                    </g:link>
                </div>
                <div class="searchAddress">
                    ${result.state}
                </div>
            </div>

</g:each>
```

How come my state name is not showing up? I've tried the following:

- ${result.state.name}
- ${result.state.code}
- ${result.state.toString()}

I'm sure the issue is a small one but, as a Grails newcomer, I can't seem to figure it out.  I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2009/04/eager-fetching-and-searchable-plugin-in.html) (Eager fetching and searchable plugin in Grails), seems like what is causing the problem, hope your problem gets resolved.